# Create container on Azure datalake Gen2

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to create container on Azure Datalake Gen2 using python code through databricks.

I have tried many variations in the code and got different errors. One of the examples is as below
The code i used (copied from stackoverflow.com) as is:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
           "https", storage_account_name), credential=my_secret_key)

#the get_file_system_client method will not throw error if the file system does not exist, if you're using the latest library 12.3.0
file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client("mytestfolder")

print("the file system exists: " + str(file_system_client.exists()))

#create the file system if it does not exist
if not file_system_client.exists():
    file_system_client.create_file_system()
    print("the file system is created.")
```

The error i am getting with this is:

```
AzureSigningError: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (37) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
```

I am looking to fix the above code or any other piece of python / pyspark code to create containers on the Gen2 Storage.
Also tried the below code as well with the same error as above.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
container_name = 'test'
storage_connection_string = f'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={acname};AccountKey={ackey};EndpointSuffix= core.windows.net;'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(storage_connection_string)
blob_service_client.create_container(container_name,public_access='CONTAINER',timeout = 10)
```

Any Help Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please leverage the below sample to create a container (filesystem) in ADLS Gen2 account and check if that helps ?

```
import os
import random
import uuid

from azure.storage.filedatalake import (
    DataLakeServiceClient,
)

def run():
    account_name = os.getenv('STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME', "MyStorageadlsgen2")
    account_key = os.getenv('STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY', "R/puXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXfSLo2PiqPXf4ltj+CUs2yg==")

    # set up the service client with the credentials from the environment variables
    service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https",
        account_name
    ), credential=account_key)

    # generate a random name for testing purpose
    fs_name = "testfs{}".format(random.randint(1, 1000))
    print("Generating a test filesystem named '{}'.".format(fs_name))

    # create the filesystem
    filesystem_client = service_client.create_file_system(file_system=fs_name)

    print("ADLS filesystem created successfully")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: That did work @NaveenBaliga. Thanks for that. The issue was however with the Storage account key. Fixed the key and my code also started working.